# Jenkinsfile: changeset directive not working for nested folders

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Does anyone know why the changeset directive is not working for nested folders?

Project structure:

```
.
└── folderA
    └── folderB
        ├── example.txt
        └── example_different_file.json
```

Pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('run with condition') {
            when {
                changeset "**/folderA/folderB/**"
            }
            steps {
                echo "Executing..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried:

1. `**/folderA/folderB/**`
2. `folderA/folderB/**`
3. `folderA/folderB/*`

but the pipeline is always skipping the stage despites making some changes in `example.txt` or `example_different_file.json`.

Comment: Do you use a multibranch pipeline?

Comment: By the way, your pipeline code has a typo: you included a `when` clause into another `when` clause. Also, have a look on [my answer to another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77708020/16417367), maybe it helps.

Comment: Good catch. I've fixed this - used this as an example. Yes, this is a multibranch pipeline project.

Comment: Ok, now to the fun part. I witnessed that for multibranch pipelines this feature doesn't work at all so I had to implement my own script that compares the diff between the current commit and target branch head, put it in the shared library, and use `expression` directive. I also assume that it has something to do with the branch source configuration, maybe there's a specific setting that prevents the correct calculation of changesets. I'm talking about Git and Butbucket Server, for other VCSs the situation may be better.